# hide Jackson fields based on costume dynamic criteria for JaxRS Respose

Tags: jackson, jersey, jax-rs, jackson2

Idea is simple. I have a object and I would like to hide some fields based on the some specific roles.

I have roles in the system "dog", "cat" etc.

```
class Food{

  String name;

  @HideInfoForTheRoles({"dog", "cat"})
  String age;
}
```

So I think to create something like that:

```
public String hideForRole(T object, String role){
// return new json
}
```

Or maybe I can override some denationalization method to force Jackson to hide field based on my annotation?

Comment: use @JsonSerialize?

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524316/1426227).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create annotation that supports on FIELD and METHOD

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface HideFor{
    String[] roles() default{};
}
```

and logic that supports annotation for both field and methods

```
public class AccessRestrictionFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {


    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, PropertyWriter writer)
            throws Exception {

        if(writer.getAnnotation(HideFor.class)!=null && isHidable( Arrays.asList(writer.getAnnotation(HideFor.class).roles()))){
            logger.debug("Found restriction on the getter method of the field: " + pojo + " Restriction For" + Arrays.toString(writer.getAnnotation(HideFor.class).roles()) );
                 return;
        }

        Field[] fields = jgen.getCurrentValue().getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        Optional<Field> field = Arrays.stream(fields)
                .filter(f-> f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(writer.getName())).findAny();

        if(field.isPresent() && field.get().getAnnotation(HideFor.class)!=null){
            if(isHidable( Arrays.asList(writer.getAnnotation(HideFor.class).roles()))){
                System.out.println("Found restriction on the field " + field.get().getName() + " Restriction For " + Arrays.toString(writer.getAnnotation(HideFor.class).roles()));
                return;
            }
        }
        writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
    }

    private boolean isHidable(List<String> rolesToHide){ // imlement the logic // }

}
```

Usage:

```
    FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("AccessRestrictionFilter", new AccessRestrictionFilter()); 
    new ObjectMapper().writer(filterProvider ).writeValueAsString(myObjToFilter);
```

I use Jersey/Spring and my configuration looks like this:

```
@Provider
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class JacksonJsonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {
    public JacksonJsonProvider(AccessRestrictionFilter filter) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
                .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                .setFilterProvider(new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("AccessRestriction", filter));
        setMapper(objectMapper);
    }
}
```

And Filter:

```
   @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    @Bean("accessRestrictionFilter")
    public AccessRestrictionFilter accessRestrictionFilter(){
          return new AccessRestrictionFilter();
    }
```

Note: in the filter I use the Security Context, because of this scope of the filter is Session (Not to share the state but create new object for each user)

and that's my POJO:

```
@JsonFilter("AccessRestrictionFilter")
public class MyClass {

    @HideFor(roles = {"ROLE_USER", "ROLE_EDITOR"})
    private int val;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@JsonView`. That's probably the easiest solution, as `@JsonView` works out-of-the-box with JAX-RS.

---

Alternativerly, it could be achieved with a `BeanPropertyFilter`, similar to [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524316/1426227) I put together a while ago.

Start defining your annotation:

```java
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD})
public @interface HiddenForRoles {

    String[] value();
}
```

Then define your `BeanPropertyFilter`, which can extend `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter`:

```java
public class HiddenForRolesPropertyFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {

    private String allowedRole;

    public HiddenForRolesPropertyFilter(String allowedRole) {
        this.allowedRole = allowedRole;
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen,
                                 SerializerProvider provider,
                                 PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {

        HiddenForRoles hiddenForRoles = writer.getAnnotation(HiddenForRoles.class);
        if (hiddenForRoles != null) {
            if (Arrays.asList(hiddenForRoles.value()).contains(allowedRole)) {
                writer.serializeAsOmittedField(pojo, jgen, provider);
                return;
            }
        }

        // If no annotation is provided, the property will be serialized
        writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
    }
}
```

Place the `@HiddenForRoles` annotation in your fields, according to your needs and ensure the class is annotated with `@JsonFilter`:

```java
@Data
@JsonFilter("hiddenForRolesPropertyFilter")
public class Foo {

    private String bar;

    @HiddenForRoles({"cat"})
    private String biz;
}
```

Finally, register the filter in a `ContextResolver` for `ObjectMapper`:

```java
String currentUserRole = // Get role from the current user

FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider()
        .addFilter("hiddenForRolesPropertyFilter",
                new HiddenForRolesPropertyFilter(currentUserRole));

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setFilterProvider(filterProvider);
```

---

If you want to make your filter "global", that is, to be applied to all beans, you can create a mix-in class and annotate it with `@JsonFilter`:

```java
@JsonFilter("hiddenForRolesPropertyFilter")
public class HiddenForRolesPropertyFilterMixIn {

}
```

Then bind the mix-in class to `Object`:

```java
mapper.addMixIn(Object.class, HiddenForRolesPropertyFilterMixIn.class);
```